# Can't seem to add js variable to parent.href.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, location

Dear stackoverflowers,

I would lik to add an variable to the following js line:

```
 setTimeout("parent.location.href = 'http://www.url.com/lists.php?listid=';",2000);
```

How do I do this? I can't seem to get the ' right.

```
 setTimeout("parent.location.href = 'http://www.url.com/lists.php?listid=' + variable;",2000);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always better to pass a function handler to `setTimeout()`. Moreover, it will easily solve your problem with placing the quotes:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    parent.location.href = "http://www.url.com/lists.php?listid=" + variable;
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function to redirect as follow....

```
function Redirect(val)
{
  parent.location.href = 'http://www.url.com/lists.php?listid='+val;
}

 setTimeout(" Redirect('"+variable+"')",2000);
```